# Website not appearing in iframe

Tags: iframe

I have to embed a third party website into a client's website but when I add the third party site it just shows blank. The website I want to iframe is www.guildelections.co.uk. I have tried other websites in the iframe and they work. I have also tried the iframing this website in other browsers but it is the same blank result.

If anyone could provide any advice on this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <iframe src="http://www.guildelections.co.uk/"></iframe>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server sets the X-Frame-Options header to explicitly stop you embedding the site in a frame. There is nothing you can do about this - if the server sets that header your browser will not display the content.

My site works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <iframe src="http://www.lenson.ro/"></iframe>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply and thats good to know. Is this and issue on the guildelections websie side as I can add other websites into the iframe on my clients site? It just seems weird how it's only www.guildelections.co.uk that is having the issue.

Comment: Google has this issue also.